# Using RET after a SYS call gives stack pointer exception

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am messing around with 8088 assembly language, what I'm trying to do is just to become familiar with function calls, so I just wrote this very basic code:

```
_EXIT = 1
_PRINTF = 127

.SECT .TEXT

main:
MOV DX, 9
MOV AX, 7
MOV BX, 2
ADD AX, BX
CALL print
CMP AX, DX
JG cond1
JE cond2
JL cond3
PUSH 0
PUSH _EXIT
SYS

print:
PUSH BP
MOV BP, SP
PUSH AX
PUSH place
PUSH _PRINTF
SYS
MOV SP, BP
POP BP
RET

cond1:
PUSH BP
MOV BP, SP
PUSH phr1
PUSH _PRINTF
SYS
MOV SP, BP
POP BP
RET

cond2:
PUSH BP
MOV BP, SP
PUSH phr2
PUSH _PRINTF
SYS
MOV SP, BP
POP BP
RET

cond3:
PUSH BP
MOV BP, SP
PUSH phr3
PUSH _PRINTF
SYS
MOV SP, BP
POP BP
RET

.SECT .DATA
place: .ASCII "NUMBER: %d \0"
phr1: .ASCII "GREAT! \0"
phr2: .ASCII "NOT SO GREAT \0"
phr3: .ASCII "DEFINITELY NOT GREAT \0"
endline: .ASCII "\n\0"

.SECT .BSS
```

Using the tracer (t88) when it reaches the cond3 instruction RET it just gives "Return on suspicious stack pointer prdepth 0".

So, what am I doing wrong? Also, bonus question which I couldn't figure why it's happening:

When SYS is called on "print" function, the value of AX register gets modified from 9 to 2, but still can't figure this out.

Comment: Which assembler do you use?  Is `SYS` some sort of macro?  It certainly is not a standard x86 instructon.

Comment: @fuz I am using the as88 assembler, and executing the code with the t88 tracer

Comment: Ah, I see.  `SYS` (opcode `0F`) is an instruction added by them for their teaching tool.

Comment: Yes. After some research I answered my bonus question: SYS eventually stores any result in the AX register, that's why AX is being modified after the SYS call on print. Yet I can't find a solution to the main question.

Comment: You are using branch intructions to call functions. You can't do that. The problem is in `JG cond1`
`JE cond2` and
`JL cond3` . Branch instructions just send you to a new address to start executing code. They are not the same as a `call` instruction. Because you effectively jumped to the functions `cond1` `cond2` and `cond3` there is no return address pushed on the stack so when it hits the `ret` instructions in the function they return to whatever happens to be on the top of stack (which isn't an actual return address)

Comment: @MichaelPetch that makes sense. But then there is any way to achieve what I am trying to do?